# Изменение свойств изображения

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, изображения

Есть ли возможность изменения свойств которые хранятся в изображении? Тип данных jpeg, интересуемые свойства Rating и Title.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие именно свойства и в каком типе изображений вас интересуют?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Тип изображений jpg. Интересуют свойства Rating и Title.

Comment: А вы уверены что эти данные хранятся в самом файле? Я вот нет... И да, информацию в сам вопрос добавьте.

Comment: Это называется EXIF. Поиск по англоязычному SO легко выдаёт нужные вопросы, [например](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226973/how-to-edit-exif-data-in-net).

Comment: @AntonPapin, Если б я еще знал что это называется EXIF. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [этой библиотеки](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet)